# Define a binary operation on {e,(12)}×{e,(123),(132)} so that it becomes isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, binary-operations, direct-product

Since {e,(12)} isomorphic to $Z_2$ and
{e,(123),(132)} isomorphic to $Z_3$ and gcd(2,3)=1, so, {e,(12)}×{e,(123),(132)} isomorphic to $Z_6$ which is not isomorphic to $S_3$.
But  can a binary operation be defined for the direct product {e,(12)}×{e,(123),(132)} so that it is isomorphic to $S_3$ ?

Comment: You are correct that the standard direct product operation doesn't give you $S_3$. But there are 216 different closed binary operations you can have on that set, and you've only checked one of them. (Not that I recommend listing all 216 and checking them one by one, but it _could_ be done that way.)

Comment: $S_3$ has $6$ elements and the direct product has $6$ too. Every 6-element set has an operation which makes it $S_3$.

Comment: @Arthur How do you know there are 216 such operations?

Comment: @markvs How do you guarantee that? And does that mean any 6 element set can be made isomorphic to both $Z_6$ and $S_3$ by suitable binary operations? And does this hold for any n-element set that it can be made isomorphic to any of the (non-isomorphic) group of that order

Comment: @Esha When constructing such a closed binary operation, you take each of the 36 pairs of elements in the product set, and assign to it one of the six elements in the product set as the "result". There are a total of $36\cdot6$ ways this process can go. So there are $36\cdot6$ different resulting operations. Not all of them are associative, not all of them have an identity or an inverse. And of those that do, not all of them are in any sensible way associated with the standard operations on $\{e,(12)\}$ and $\{e,(123),(132)\}$. Again, it's not the approach I recommend, but it is possible.

Comment: @Arthur I did not get why 36×6 ways ? Can you please elaborate?(It might be a silly question but I did not understand it, that's why I am asking again. Pardon.)

Comment: You know what, it's $6^{36}$, not $6\cdot36$. I done goofed. In that case, I **really** don't recommend you list them all and check them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As markvs has noted in the comments, every set with 6 elements has an operation that gives it a group structure isomorphic to $S_{3}$.

Here's how it works: let $X$ be a set with $6$ elements. Since $S_{3}$ also has 6 elements, there exists a bijection $f \colon X \to S_{3}$. Now, we can define a binary operation $\circ \colon X \times X \to X$ on $X$ by using the bijection $f$.

Informally, given two elements $x, y$ of $X$, we define their product in the following way: first, use the bijection $f$ to find the corresponding elements $f(x), f(y) \in S_{3}$. Then, find the product of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ in $S_{3},$ where we already have a defined group operation. Finally, use the inverse bijection $f^{-1}$ to find the element of $X$ that corresponds to the product in $S_{3}$; this will be the product of $x$ and $y$.

So, this gives us the following definition: For each $(x, y) \in X \times X,$ let $$x \circ y = f^{-1}(f(x) \cdot f(y)),$$ where $\cdot$ denotes the group operation of $S_{3}$. You should check that $\circ$ actually makes $X$ a group, by checking the following:

1. $\circ$ is well-defined.
2. $\circ$ is associative.
3. $(X, \circ)$ has an identity element $e$.
4. Each element $x \in X$ has an inverse $x^{-1}$ such that $x \circ x^{-1} = e = x^{-1} \circ x.$

All of these can be verified by using the fact that $f, f^{-1}$ are both bijections, and that $S_{3}$ already has a group structure.

Now, we claim that $(X, \circ)$ and $(S_{3}, \cdot)$ are isomorphic as groups. We basically get this for free: we already have a bijection $f \colon X \to S_{3},$ and note that the definition of $\circ$ implies that for all $x, y \in X,$
$$f( x \circ y) = f(x) \cdot f(y).$$ Clearly, $f$ is a homomorphism from $(X, \circ)$ to $(S_{3}, \cdot).$ Since it is also bijective, is is an isomorphism, and we are done.

This process is known as transport of structure, and allows us to give a set $X$ a group structure whenever there exists a bijection between $X$ and another set $G$ which already has a group structure.

Applying this to your question, you can simply take $f \colon \{e,(12)\} \times \{e,(123),(132)\} \to S_{3}$ to be your favorite bijection between the two, and then define the group structure using the above process. Of course, given the names of the elements in $\{e,(12)\} \times \{e,(123),(132)\}$, things might get a little confusing.